# How to show user when a register have a database contraints instead an exception stacktrace?

Tags: java, database, exception

i have the following catch block:

```
            try {
                actorController.destroy(act.getActorId());
            } catch (Exception ex){
                AlertDialog.showAlertDialog("Error", "Error", ex.getMessage());
            }
```

how to tell users that there is a record with constraint instead get this

[Catch message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viaRM.png)

I am working in java.

Comment: Don't call `ex.getMessage()`? Supply your own message?

Comment: Your question title doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What does 'when a register have database constraints' mean? Are you by any chance looking for `catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException exc)`?

Answer (score -1):

you catch another type of exception SQLException.
This is more related to database operations.